# trigger is not updating table

Tags: oracle, plsql

I created a trigger that updates a table I created whenever I update a column in a different table. So far my trigger compiles but when I updated the column the trigger doesn't seem to fire or do anything.
Can anyone help me?

```
CREATE TABLE bb_sales_sum (
    idProduct number(2) NOT NULL,
    total number(6,2),
    quantity number); 


CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER BB_SALESUM_TRG
    AFTER UPDATE OF orderplaced on bb_basket 
    FOR EACH ROW
    WHEN (NEW.orderplaced = 1)
DECLARE 
    lv_count Number;
BEGIN   
    if :new.orderplaced = 1 then 
        for item in 
            (select idproduct, (quantity * price) AS total, quantity
            from bb_basketitem
            where idbasket = :old.idbasket)
    loop
        select count(*)
        into lv_count
        from bb_sales_sum where idProduct = item.idproduct;

        if lv_count = NULL then
            INSERT INTO bb_sales_sum
            VALUES (item.idproduct, item.total, item.quantity);
        else
            update bb_sales_sum 
            set quantity = item.quantity where
            idProduct = item.idproduct;
        end if;
    end loop;
    end if;

END; 
/
update bb_basket 
set orderplaced = 1 
where idbasket = 14;

select * from bb_sales_sum;
```

Comment: What's wrong with [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55998327/7998591) to your previous question to the same problem?  Did you try? Note that `if lv_count = NULL` will never be true. `count(*)` always returns 0 or the actual count. Moreover, even if were true, `something  = NULL`  isn't the right way to compare a `null`

Comment: I'm not familiar at all with doing merges. Was wondering if there was a different way to do it?

Comment: I do appreciate your help though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use a similar `MERGE` statement using the values from  `bb_basketitem` instead of a for loop.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER BB_SALESUM_TRG
  AFTER UPDATE OF orderplaced on bb_basket 
    FOR EACH ROW 
 WHEN (NEW.orderplaced = 1)
BEGIN   
   MERGE INTO bb_sales_sum t USING 
      (  select idproduct, (quantity * price) AS total, quantity
                    from bb_basketitem item
                        where idbasket = :old.idbasket 
         ) s  
         ON (s.idproduct = t.idproduct ) 
             WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
                SET  quantity  = s.quantity
              WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
         INSERT (
              idproduct,quantity,total)
         VALUES
              ( s.idproduct,s.quantity,s.total );          

END; 
/
```

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=6c0deb0968115e232823a7f105d2a319)